# Beginning C. variable not being initilized

Tags: c

I am new to C programming. It says i am not initializing myLetter and I keep getting a runtime error

Here is my code:

```
    #include    <stdio.h>
    #include    <string.h>
    #include    <ctype.h>
    // MAXWORD, which will be the max word length 
    #define     MAXWORD     20
    // INCORRECT_GUESSES, which will be the max guesses
    #define     INCORRECT_GUESSES   6

    /* Prototypes */

    // Fills theArray with howMany copies of theLetter
    void    fill_array( char *theArray, int howMany, char theLetter );

    // Get char from player, checks the letter, shows progress so far
    int     get_letter( char *theWord, char *soFar );

    // Check if letter is in word, updates progress so far
    int     letter_in_word( char *theWord, char *soFar, char theLetter );

    // Convert the word to lowercase
    void    lower_string( char *someWord );

    // Play one game
    void    play( char *theWord );

    /* Function definitions */

    int main( )
    {
        char theWord [ MAXWORD ];
        FILE*   word;
        word = fopen( "guesswords.txt", "r" );

        if ( word == NULL )
        {
            printf( "No input file found..........\n" );
            return -1;
        }

        fscanf( word, "%s", theWord );
        printf( "%s\n", theWord );

        lower_string( theWord );
        printf( "%s\n", theWord ); 

        play( theWord );

        fclose( word );
        return 0;
    }

    // Get char from player, checks the letter, shows progress so far
    int get_letter( char *theWord, char *soFar )
    {
        char theLetter;
        printf("\nPlease enter a letter: ");
        scanf( " %c", theLetter );
        theLetter = tolower(theLetter);

        letter_in_word( theWord, soFar, theLetter );

        return theLetter;
    }

    // Fills theArray with howMany copies of theLetter
    void fill_array( char *theArray, int howMany, char theLetter )
    {
        int i;
        for( i=0; i<howMany; i++ )
        {
            theArray[i]= theLetter;
            *(theArray + i) = theLetter;
            *theArray = theLetter;
        }
        theArray[howMany] = '\0';
    }

    // Check if letter is in word, updates progress so far
    int letter_in_word( char *theWord, char *soFar, char theLetter )
    {
        int i;
        int num=0;
        int len = strlen(theWord);

        for( i=0; i<len; i++)
        {
            if (theWord[i] == theLetter )
            {
                soFar[i] = theLetter;
                num++;
            }
        }
        if (num == 0)
        {
            printf( "SORRY! your letter is not in the word\n" );
            return 0;

        }
        else if (num>0)
        {
            printf( "Congratz! your letter was in the word\n" );
            printf("%s", soFar);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    // Convert the word to lowercase
    void lower_string( char *someWord )
    {
        int i, cha;
        int len = strlen( someWord );
        for( i=0; i<len; i++ )
        {
            cha = someWord[i];
            cha = tolower(cha);
            someWord[i] = cha;
        }
    }

    // Play one game
    void play( char *theWord )
    {
        int i;
        int len = strlen(theWord);
        int guess = INCORRECT_GUESSES;
        int result = 0;
        char soFar[MAXWORD];
        fill_array( soFar, len, '*');
        printf( "%c", soFar ); 

        for( i=0; i<INCORRECT_GUESSES; i++ ) 
        {
            get_letter( theWord, soFar );
            if( get_letter == 0)
            {
                printf( "Sorry, you're out of guesses" ); 
            }
            else
            {
                printf( "You win");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: C++ is not C. You should think twice before tagging both.

Comment: can't find `myLetter`?!

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Please post the exact error and the line number.

Comment: I'm sure it doesn't say you're not initialising `myLetter`, since there is no `myLetter` in the program. What is the exact error, which line does it refer to, and why have you tagged the question C++ when it's about C?

Answer (score 3):

```
scanf( " %c", theLetter );
```

should be

```
scanf( " %c", &theLetter );
```

Time to learn about arrays and pointers. Can't put it off for very long if you're a C programmer.

Comment: You might also mention: `printf( "%c", soFar );` which should use `%s`.

Comment: No problem. The thing to understand is why `scanf( " %c", &theLetter );` needs `&` but `fscanf( word, "%s", theWord );` does not.

Comment: @john: I'd disagree with well-spotted and just refer to the output of a compiler: https://gist.github.com/sharth/20d0058538825fc747fc

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with how scanf() is used. Please use this [link] to see some details.

if you repace :
scanf( " %c", theLetter )
with:
scanf( " %c", &theLetter )
then everything will be OK.

Full Working Code:

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <string.h>
#include    <ctype.h>
// MAXWORD, which will be the max word length
#define     MAXWORD     20
// INCORRECT_GUESSES, which will be the max guesses
#define     INCORRECT_GUESSES   6

/* Prototypes */

// Fills theArray with howMany copies of theLetter
void    fill_array( char *theArray, int howMany, char theLetter );

// Get char from player, checks the letter, shows progress so far
int     get_letter( char *theWord, char *soFar );

// Check if letter is in word, updates progress so far
int     letter_in_word( char *theWord, char *soFar, char theLetter );

// Convert the word to lowercase
void    lower_string( char *someWord );

// Play one game
void    play( char *theWord );

/* Function definitions */

int main( )
{
    char theWord [ MAXWORD ];
    FILE*   word;
    word = fopen( "guesswords.txt", "r" );

    if ( word == NULL )
    {
        printf( "No input file found..........\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    fscanf( word, "%s", theWord );
    printf( "%s\n", theWord );

    lower_string( theWord );
    printf( "%s\n", theWord );

    play( theWord );

    fclose( word );
    return 0;
}

// Get char from player, checks the letter, shows progress so far
int get_letter( char *theWord, char *soFar )
{
    char theLetter;
    printf("\nPlease enter a letter: ");
    scanf( " %c", &theLetter );
    theLetter = tolower(theLetter);

    letter_in_word( theWord, soFar, theLetter );

    return theLetter;
}

// Fills theArray with howMany copies of theLetter
void fill_array( char *theArray, int howMany, char theLetter )
{
    int i;
    for( i=0; i<howMany; i++ )
    {
        theArray[i]= theLetter;
        *(theArray + i) = theLetter;
        *theArray = theLetter;
    }
    theArray[howMany] = '\0';
}

// Check if letter is in word, updates progress so far
int letter_in_word( char *theWord, char *soFar, char theLetter )
{
    int i;
    int num=0;
    int len = strlen(theWord);

    for( i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        if (theWord[i] == theLetter )
        {
            soFar[i] = theLetter;
            num++;
        }
    }
    if (num == 0)
    {
        printf( "SORRY! your letter is not in the word\n" );
        return 0;

    }
    else if (num>0)
    {
        printf( "Congratz! your letter was in the word\n" );
        printf("%s", soFar);
        return 1;
    }
}

// Convert the word to lowercase
void lower_string( char *someWord )
{
    int i, cha;
    int len = strlen( someWord );
    for( i=0; i<len; i++ )
    {
        cha = someWord[i];
        cha = tolower(cha);
        someWord[i] = cha;
    }
}

// Play one game
void play( char *theWord )
{
    int i;
    int len = strlen(theWord);
    int guess = INCORRECT_GUESSES;
    int result = 0;
    char soFar[MAXWORD];
    fill_array( soFar, len, '*');
    printf( "%c", soFar );

    for( i=0; i<INCORRECT_GUESSES; i++ )
    {
        get_letter( theWord, soFar );
        if( get_letter == 0)
        {
            printf( "Sorry, you're out of guesses" );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "You win");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int get_letter( char *theWord, char *soFar )
{
    char theLetter;
    printf("\nPlease enter a letter: ");
    scanf( " %c", &theLetter );   // <--- rigth here
    theLetter = tolower(theLetter);

    letter_in_word( theWord, soFar, theLetter );

    return theLetter;
}
```